# Difference between amnesty and exonerate

Tags: meaning

*Amnesty* is a noun meaning:

> an official pardon for people who have been convicted of political offences

Whereas *exonerate* is a verb meaning:

> (of an official body) absolve (someone) from blame for a fault or wrongdoing

What is the difference between the two? Is *amnesty* used exclusively for political pardons only?

Comment: I don't think an ***amnesty*** is an "official pardon" - all it means is the authorities undertake *not to prosecute* those who've broken the rules (always supposing they've stopped their wrongdoing, and will not resume). Without looking it up I assume it's effectively "We'll forget about your sinful past*, from the same root as ***amnesia***. But it's not my job to look it up. Have you?

Comment: I don't know where you got those definitions from, but (a) I agree with fumblefingers' definition of amnesty, and (b) *exonerate*, in Merriam-Webster, is "to prove someone is not guilty".  So it's the difference between "I'll pretend you never did that even though we both know you did" and "It is proven that you never did that."

Answer (score 0):

That is just one of the meanings of *amnesty*. It can also apply to other crimes and misdemeanours: for instance, under a *gun amnesty*, people who illegally possess guns can hand them in at a police station without fear of prosecution. But the implication is that people guilty of a past crime will not be faced with punishment.

*Exoneration* is quite different: a person is *exonerated* of a charge if they are proven innocent.

Answer (score 0):

A few corrections:

1. *Amnesty* is not a *pardon*: *amnesty* is given to a class of people; *a pardon* is granted to named individuals.
2. *Amnesty* is not given to political prisoners only; in fact, an amnesty may well specifically exclude political prisoners, in regimes that do have them.
3. *Amnesty* does not imply *exoneration*. A prisoner may be released from prison due to an amnesty declared on a special anniversary, but their criminal record remains unchanged.
4. Amnesty (esp. one given to political prisoners) *may* include exoneration. In the Soviet bloc, the term [*rehabilitation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rehabilitation_%28Soviet%29) was used for this type of amnesties that were given in post-Stalinist and post-Communist times.
5. *Exonerate* does not mean *to prove that someone is not guilty* (despite what M-W says). For example, a convicted person may be exonerated by an appellate court on a technicality, without having proven anything.